# Swift extension method for Alamofire to return SwiftyJSON result

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I migrated an app from Swift 2.2 to 3.0 which used an extension method from the [Alamofire-SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/Alamofire-SwiftyJSON) project on GitHub. Alamofire-SwiftyJSON allows receiving the response from an Alamofire network request converted to a SwiftyJSON instance like this:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
    .responseSwiftyJSON({ (request, response, json, error) in
        print(json) // json is a SwiftyJSON 'JSON' instance
        print(error)
    })
```

The Alamofire-SwiftyJSON project was not updated for Swift 3 as of writing this question. I'm looking for an equivalent implementation of the `responseSwiftyJSON` extension method that works with Swift 3+ and Alamofire 4+.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Extension Methods

This solution incorporates a suggestion for working with Alamofire from the [SwiftyJSON readme](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#work-with-alamofire).

It is based on similar extensions included with Alamofire in [ResponseSerialization.swift](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/ResponseSerialization.swift):

- `DataRequest.responseJSON(queue:options:completionHandler:)`
- `DataRequest.jsonResponseSerializer(options:)`

This solution works with Swift 3 and above. It was tested with Alamofire 4.2+ and SwiftyJSON 3.1.3+.

```
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

extension DataRequest {

    /// Adds a handler to be called once the request has finished.
    ///
    /// - parameter options:           The JSON serialization reading options. Defaults to `.allowFragments`.
    /// - parameter completionHandler: A closure to be executed once the request has finished.
    ///
    /// - returns: The request.
    @discardableResult
    public func responseSwiftyJSON(
        queue: DispatchQueue? = nil,
        options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions = .allowFragments,
        completionHandler: @escaping (DataResponse<JSON>) -> Void) -> Self {
            return response(
                queue: queue,
                responseSerializer: DataRequest.swiftyJSONResponseSerializer(options: options),
                completionHandler: completionHandler
            )
    }

    /// Creates a response serializer that returns a SwiftyJSON instance result type constructed from the response data using
    /// `JSONSerialization` with the specified reading options.
    ///
    /// - parameter options: The JSON serialization reading options. Defaults to `.allowFragments`.
    ///
    /// - returns: A SwiftyJSON response serializer.
    public static func swiftyJSONResponseSerializer(
        options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions = .allowFragments) -> DataResponseSerializer<JSON> {
            return DataResponseSerializer { _, response, data, error in
                let result = Request.serializeResponseJSON(options: options, response: response, data: data, error: error)
                switch result {
                    case .success(let value):
                        return .success(JSON(value))
                    case .failure(let error):
                        return .failure(error)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

**Example Use:**

```
Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/get").validate().responseSwiftyJSON {
        response in

        print("Response: \(response)")

        switch response.result {
            case .success(let json):
                // Use SwiftyJSON instance
                print("JSON: \(json)")

            case .failure(let error):
                // Handle error
                print("Error: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Gnarly, but elegant once you understand what Alamofire is doing. The completionHandler gets called on the thread that queue is running on or the main thread if queue is nil. The responseSerializer gets called on an NSOperationQueue internal to Alamofire.  I would add a call to validate() as in the SWiftyJSON readme.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @user992167! I added the validate() method as you suggested.